# Field *** is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null selenium page factory

Tags: c#, selenium, findby

I'm having trouble with selenium and page factory and I don't really know what else to do.

I'm trying initialize an element with the following code:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sign-up-btn")]
private IWebElement signUpButton;
```

However I keep getting the error "Field 'signUpButton' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

Why isn't pagefactor.initelements initializing the value?

I have this in a base file:

```
public Page()
{
    PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
}
```

Which my page file (homepage) is inheriting.

why wouldn't the variable be assigned?

Comment: You don't have any code like `signUpButton = ` anywhere.

Comment: I've not had to do that before with pagefactory and findsby. I usually do the above, then have signupbutton.click().

Comment: `PageFactory` isn't a variable.

Comment: By variable I mean the iwebelement signInButton

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler is not able to tell the `PageFactory.InitElements(...)` method assigns a value to this field using class reflection, so it complains. It is a warning you can ignore if you want.

If you *really* want to get rid of it, change your field to an auto property:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sign-up-btn")]
public IWebElement SignUpButton { get; set; }
```

Or you can just use the expression bodied syntax to return the element directly instead of using class reflection:

```
private IWebElement SignUpButton => Driver.FindElement(By.Id("sign-up-btn"));
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Out of curiosity, would the code run through if I chose to ignore the issue?

Comment: @thegoatboy: yes, the code would run fine. It is a warning, not a compiler error.

Comment: hmm ok. At the moment it stops the test as the iwebelement is null. I'll see what happens when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok it was my error.

I was using `using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;`

But I should have been using `using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;`

I still do get the null error message, but changing to seleniumExtras.pageObjects and the code doesn't fall over.

Thanks for the input everyone.